# How to append 0s at the end of varbinary value in SQL

Tags: sql, varbinary

I have a column named abc which is Varbinary.
I want to insert 0s at the end of varbinary value of fixed length.

For example

This is original value : `0x0A5445535420`

And I want something like this:
`0x0A5445535420200000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

I tried

```
CONVERT(VARBINARY(64), 'abc')
```

but it is not appending 0s at the end.

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: Sql server 2012

Comment: Apparently, all you need is to convert it to `BINARY` instead of `VARBINARY`, as varbinary will automatically cut off zeros. May I ask why you use varbinary if you want values of fixed length ?

Comment: Thank you Rafalon, I didn't knew the difference between BINARY and VARBINARY. If I use (CONVERT(BINARY(64), 'abc') it does not cut off zeroes. Thank you again.

Comment: Well `VAR` stands for "variable" (variable length) like in `VARCHAR`. It means only significant digits/chars/whatever are kept in memory. Those types are used to optimize memory. Hence, the length you declare (64) is the *maximum* length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(64), (CONVERT(BINARY(64), 'abc')))
```

Comment: `SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(64), (CONVERT(BINARY(64), 'abc')))` gives me the same as `SELECT CONVERT(BINARY(64), 'abc')` alone (`0x61626300000...000`)

Comment: @Rafalon modulo the data type, yes, but not the same as `CONVERT(VARBINARY(64), 'abc')` which is what was posted.  I don't know whether the exact data type (VARBINARY vs BINARY) is important to the OP, hence I proposed what he asked for.

Comment: @Joe that's right, so you answered the question :) but I think you could improve your answer by adding a note on types because it might be useful to those who asks themselves this kind of questions